# Why nginx $request_uri contains only one parameter?

Tags: nginx, get

My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.app;
    location / {
      echo $request_uri;
    }
}
```

Then i perform GET request via curl and i can see only first parameter. All others are lost:

```
# curl http://test.app?p1=v1&p2=v2
> /?p1=v1
```

As i understand, $request_uri should contains all GET arguments. Why they are lost?

Nginx is installed via apt-get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the & if you do a curl on the command line otherwise you will do `curl http://test.app?p1=v1` and send it to the background.

`curl http://test.app?p1=v1\&p2=v2` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, it works! But how this can be fixed to work in nginx?

Comment: It has nothing to do with nginx, but with the way you test with curl.
`curl "http://test.app?p1=v1&p2=v2"` does the same.